# Wine Configuration dialog box way too small for Wine version 1.8.3

Tags: upgrade, wine, fonts, dialog

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The Wine Configuration dialog box for Wine version 1.8.3 is way too small to see the fonts inside the box. I have uninstalled and reinstalled Wine 1.8.3 a couple of times now using the command line but it does not do any good. Previously I had Wine 1.6.2 (also,the dialog box was way too small along with very small fonts) installed and upgraded to Wine 1.8.3.  I thought that if I upgraded to Wine 1.8.3 the problem would go away but it has not. How do I make it bigger?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 3):

This is usually the problem if your laptop has a high resolution display . Once you open Wine Configuration dialog box just navigate to the Graphics tab at the top and increase the slide bar which says screen resolution. 
close and reopen the application. This hopefully solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about making the Terminal window larger in font size or the entire Wine window (encapsulating the entire Ubuntu OS GUI)?

If Terminal, left click somewhere in the terminal window, then move your mouse to the top of the screen where a menu should suddenly show up. Edit -> Profile Preferences, then crank up the font size in the General tab by click on the font name and at the bottom right is the font size.

Comment: No. I am talking about the Wine Configuration dialog box being so, so small.  It has text in it but everything is so, so small.  It is too small to see anything.  This is the problem and NOT the terminal window.